# Group by related entries field

Tags: templating, craft3, entries-field, group

I have a channel of Musical Compositions:

[image]

Now all these Compositions have a Composer.
All the composers are stored in a separate channel and then linked with their respective compositions trough a [entries field](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/entries-fields.html)

Now I like to order the compositions by the last name of the composer and group them together alphabetically.

I managed them to be grouped but not by the composer name, just by the composition title which is not helpful.

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('komposition').limit(null) %}
{% set allEntriesByPrename = allEntries | group('title|upper|slice(0, 1)') %}

{% for letter, allEntriesSorted in allEntriesByPrename %} 
 {# stuff #}
{% endfor %}
```

Now the catch here is the group filter I guess but when I use the handle of the entries field it doesn't work:

```
| group('composerRelated.lastName|upper|slice(0, 1)')
```

If I write it like this, the group filter simply is ignored. Since the entries field returns an array I have no idea how to write this. And I think at the time of the group filter the entries field is not available yet.

I also tried to grab all composers from the section and put it into the group filter:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('komposition').limit(null) %}
{% set composerName = craft.entries.section('komponist').limit(null) %}

{% set allEntriesByPrename = allEntries | group('composerName.lastName|upper|slice(0, 1)') %}
```

This is too much inception for me. How do I have to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're nearly there! Give this a shot:

```
{% set allEntriesByPrename = allEntries | group('{{ (object.composerName | first).lastName | upper | slice(0, 1) }}') %}
```

I believe the issue is that relations always come back as an *array*, and you were trying to immediately access a property of the `Element` at index `0` in that array, rather than de-referencing it, *then* accessing the property.

Be aware that this may generate some deprecation errors, as using the `first` filter will attempt to use the relational field as an array. Instead, I'd recommend eager-loading your Composers along with the Compositions--in addition to being safer, moving forward, it avoids an N+1 problem, and will *dramatically* reduce the number of queries on your page:

```
{# See: `with`, including the `composerName` field handle: #}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries({
  section: 'komposition',
  limit: null,
  with: [
    ['composerName']
  ]
}).all()

{# Grouping by a relation will no longer trigger another query per Composition: #}
{% set allEntriesByPrename = allEntries | group('{{ (object.composerName | first).lastName | upper | slice(0, 1) }}') %}
```

> **Note:** I had to use the expanded syntax for the `group` filter (`{{ ... }}`) in order to enforce the proper order of operations. In that context, `object` is a reference to the Composition.

Comment: If I wrap the group filter into `{{}}` I get  `A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "}" ("punctuation" expected with value ":")`

Comment: Is it still surrounded with single quotes, or did you remove those in the process?

Comment: yes is use single quotes: `{% set allEntriesByPrename = allEntries | group('{{object.composerName | first .lastName|upper|slice(0, 1)}}') %}`

Comment: Same like this: `{% set allEntriesByPrename = allEntries | group('{{ (object.komponistRelated | first).nachname | upper | slice(0, 1) }}') %}`

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party here, but in case anyone else comes across this post.

The suggestion that August was making [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/33348/10878) was very close, but when I tried something similar, I was running into the same error as @KSPR

`A hash key must be followed by a colon (:). Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "}" ("punctuation" expected with value ":")`

According to the docs for Crafts [twig group filter](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/filters.html#group) what you actually need is something like this:

```
{% set allEntriesByPrename = allEntries | group( e => (e.composerName| first).lastName | upper | slice(0, 1) ) %}
```